# How to set selected value on select using selectpicker plugin from bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using the [Bootstrap-Select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) plugin like this:

**HTML**:

```html
<select name="selValue" class="selectpicker">
   <option value="1">Val 1</option>
   <option value="2">Val 2</option>
   <option value="3">Val 3</option>
   <option value="4">Val 4</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**:

```js
$('select[name=selValue]').selectpicker();
```

Now I want to set the value selected to this select when button clicked... something like this:

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
   $('select[name=selValue]').val(1);
});
```

But nothing happens.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to achieve, the value is set once user click on that option in the select

Comment: Yes because really the value comes from a method on an ajax call...

Comment: The value is correctly selected, but you didn't see it because the plugin hide the real select and show a button with an unordered list

Comment: Yes I know that, but how to fix it... I mean... the user must see the selection on this control

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The value is correctly selected, but you didn't see it because the plugin hide the real select and show a button with an unordered list, so, if you want that the user see the selected value on the select you can do something like this:

```
//Get the text using the value of select
var text = $("select[name=selValue] option[value='1']").text();
//We need to show the text inside the span that the plugin show
$('.bootstrap-select .filter-option').text(text);
//Check the selected attribute for the real select
$('select[name=selValue]').val(1);
```

#### Edit:

Like @blushrt points out, a better solution is:

```
$('select[name=selValue]').val(1);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
```

#### Edit 2:

To select multiple values, pass the values as an array.

Comment: A better solution would just be: `$('select[name=selValue]').val(1);$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');` This way you are only changing the hidden select, callling selectpicker('refresh') redraws the button.

Comment: yes, this way is better @blushrt, added to my answer

Comment: I am facing the same issue that i am unable to select preselected values which user has selected privously.

Comment: Is it necessary to refresh the selectpicker after it ?? @TomSarduy

Comment: @ankitsuthar, yes

Comment: Actually it's `$(.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');`. Refresh will change the style of the element.

Comment: Parsing selected values as an array works for me.

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching every where trying to understand how to show the proper selected option without relying soley on the text.

Comment: this no longer works it seems.  'selectpicker is not a function' error

Answer (score 84):

```
$('select[name=selValue]').val(1);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

This is all you need to do. No need to change the generated html of selectpicker directly, just change the hidden select field, and then call the selectpicker('refresh').

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Calling the .selectpicker('refresh') command is crucial to selection and update the current value of a selectpicker powered dropdownlist. Please note, calling refresh on ALL .selectpicker elements can be slow. If you konw the object to operate- its preferred to call refresh on that single select list.

Comment: `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');`  can kill your performance if you have a lot of selectpickers on one page

Comment: Another problem I found is, This won't tick the selection.

Answer (score 51):

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', YOUR_VALUE);
```

Comment: I have tried your solution.. but its showing 'nothing selected' in my select, though I have selected value and I am getting same from resource where i am storing data.

Answer (score 17):

No refresh is needed if the "val"-parameter is used for setting the value, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0xicCode/96ntuxnz/). Use brackets for the value to enable multiple selected values.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', [1]);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
   $('select[name=selValue]').val(1);
   $('select[name=selValue]').change();
});
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Actually your value is set, but your selectpicker is not refreshed

As you can read from documentation 
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerval

The right way to do this would be

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 1);
```

For multiple values you can add array of values

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', [1 , 2]);
```

Answer (score 8):

`$('selector').selectpicker('val',value);`

in place of selector you can give you selector either class or id for example: `$('#mySelect').selectpicker('val',your_value)`

Comment: i get an error 'selectpicker is not a function'.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the selected value by calling the val method on the element.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', 'Mustard');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['Mustard','Relish']);
```

This will select all items in a multi-select.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('selectAll');
```

details are available on site : https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/

Comment: I have tried your solution.. but its showing 'nothing selected' in my select, though I have selected value and I am getting same from resource where i am storing data.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker("val", "value");
```

Comment: Abd, i have php script that pass json format to ajax where the json format is like that: *"car":"8","colors":"red,blue,white"}*. In this case how can insert the object "colors" as checked inside selectpicker using this method *$('.selectpicker').selectpicker("val", "data.colors");*?

Answer (score 3):

When you use **Bootstrap Selectpicke**r then you should use this to get the selected option's value.

```
$('#membershipadmin').selectpicker("option:selected").val();
```

Comment: Best solution for setup value to the bootstrap select picker i found

Answer (score 3):

Not a single one of these solutions helped.  In my case, i was using Bootstrap 5.x and v1.14.x of boostrap-select.

In case it helps anyone else the solution was to make sure jquery was loaded before bootstrap-select.  when that is done, this works

```
$('#sel_control').selectpicker('val','1010');
```

Comment: this solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation of **blushrt's** answer for when you do not have "hard coded" values for options (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.)

Let's say you render a `<select>` with options values being GUIDs of some users. Then you will need to somehow extract the value of the option in order to set it on the `<select>`.

In the following we select the first option of the select.

**HTML**:

```html
<select name="selValue" class="selectpicker">
   <option value="CD23E546-9BD8-40FD-BD9A-3E2CBAD81A39">Dennis</option>
   <option value="4DDCC643-0DE2-4B78-8393-33A716E3AFF4">Robert</option>
   <option value="D3017807-86E2-4E56-9F28-961202FFF095">George</option>
   <option value="991C2782-971E-41F8-B532-32E005F6A349">Ivanhoe</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**:

```js
// Initialize the select picker.
$('select[name=selValue]').selectpicker();

// Extract the value of the first option.
var sVal = $('select[name=selValue] option:first').val();

// Set the "selected" value of the <select>.
$('select[name=selValue]').val(sVal);

// Force a refresh.
$('select[name=selValue]').selectpicker('refresh');
```

We used this in a select with the multiple keyword `<select multiple>`. In this case nothing is selected per default, but we wanted the first item to always be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @blushrt 's great answer I will update this response. 
Just using -

```
$("#Select_ID").val(id);
```

works if you've preloaded everything you need to the selector.

Answer (score 2):

This will not trigger an `onChange` on picker element (if any):

```js
$(element).val(myVal)
$(element).selectpicker('refresh')
```

If on change is to be also triggered:

```js
$(element).val(myVal)
$(element).selectpicker('refresh').trigger('change') // also trigger 'change'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bar= $(#foo).find("option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can just call this for multi-value

`$(<your select picker>).selectpicker("val", ["value1", "value2"])`

You can find more here https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selectpicker option:selected').val();
```

Just put option:selected to get value, because the bootstrap selectpicker change to  and appear in diferent way. But select still there selected

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, perfectly, every time was the following (Bootstrap 3.4.1):

```
   $("#myDropDown").val(MyDropDownValue).change();
```

as in:

```
   $("#ddlSalutations").val(data.SalutationID).change();
```

None of the methods posted here work (any more) as you'll always get the following error in your browser. Something must have changed since.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

Comment: im still going crazy.  does this work w/ 'live search'?  tried the latest beta also - no luck.
i am using bootstrap 5.x though

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '0');
```

With the '0' being the value of the item you want selected

Answer (score 0):

Well another way to do it is, with ***this*** keyword, you can simply get the object in ***this*** and manipulate it's value. Eg :

```
$("select[name=selValue]").click(
    function() {
        $(this).val(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name=selValue]').selectpicker('val', '1')
```

works fine.

But

```
var variable = '2' 

$('select[name=selValue]').selectpicker('val', variable);
```

is not working with Bootstrap 5. In BS 4 it works.

Answer (score 0):

simply add an option before the other option so it will be automatically appended

```
<select name="class" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
   <option value="" selected>I am default selected text</option>
   <option value="9a">9A</option>
   <option value="9b">9B</option>
</select>
```

**note:** empty option will not considered, it will display Nothing selected from plugin

Answer (score -2):

User ID For element, then

```
document.getElementById('selValue').value=Your Value;
$('#selValue').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score -3):

use this and it's gonna work:

```
 $('select[name=selValue]').selectpicker('val', 1);
```

Comment: $(...).selectpicker is not a function