# Jquery selectpicker default selected value from selectbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

My main problem was I was trying to get values from my form and selectboxes are using selectpicker jquery plugin, they look really cool now! But in other I found a bug, when I put default selected by html tag "selected" it always gives selected value.

https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select

I'm trying to get value by this code but it always return same value.

```
var pets_name = $('#pets_name').val();
```

Comment: Duplicate?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to search setting default value option but I couldn't find anything about it on seletpickers github.

I solved my problem by this code. :selected gives us this value. I hope it will help someone,sometimes we need small fixes not big ones.

```
var pets_name = $('#pets_name:selected').val();
```