# Issue on Setting HTML Select Option Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I am trying to change selected item from the list options dynamically at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/atz013n5/3/) but it is not working.

```
<select id="selItems" class="selectpicker">
    <option>Select From List</option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
<p>
<button id="setdefault" type="submit" class="btn">Set Default</button>

<script>
 $("#setdefault").on("click", function () {
   $("#selItems option:eq(2)").attr("selected", "selected");
 });
</script>
```

can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `select` has an ID of `setdefault`... Therer is no `selItems`

Comment: thanks tymeJV , I fixed the code but still same thing happening!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set selected value on select using selectpicker plugin from bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```js
 $("#setdefault").on("click", function () {
   $("#selItems option:eq(2)").prop("selected", true);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selItems" class="selectpicker">
    <option>Select From List</option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
<p>
<button id="setdefault" type="submit" class="btn">Set Default</button>
```

Comment: Thanks jrummell it was a wise hint!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr for more about prop vs attr.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap Select has a method for doing this. You shouldn't be manually manipulating attributes because the element seen in the page isn't the original select element anyway.

```
$("#setdefault").on("click", function () {
    $("#selItems").selectpicker('val', 'Ketchup');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/atz013n5/6/)

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#methods

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why your code is not working how you expect it to.

You are setting a click event on your select element, and not on the "set default" button.

Your actual select element is not visible on the page because it is being replaced by the jquery plugin you are using.. so even if you set the selected attribute of your select, you won't see it on the page.

You should refer to [the documentation of that plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to figure out how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching

```
$("#setdefault").on("click",function(){
 $("#selItems option:eq(3)").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

to

```
$("#setdefault").on("click",function(){
 $("#setdefault option:eq(3)").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Comment: `#setdefault` is not a `select` element

Answer (score 0):

Just use `val()`:

```js
$("#setdefault").on("click", function() {
  $("#selItems").val("Mustard");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selItems" class="selectpicker">
  <option>Select From List</option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
<p>
<button id="setdefault" type="submit" class="btn">Set Default</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Rudolph but u miss the Bootstrap Part!