# Bootstrap Select - Set selected value by text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

How can I change the drop down if I only know the text and not the value?

Here is my select -

```
 <select id="app_id" class="selectpicker">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="1">Application 1</option>
       <option value="2">Application 2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: so you want to know by the text inside of the drop-down, what is the value? You can use jQuery for in a if-statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap

Comment: Or do you want to set an option to selected by its text?

Comment: @mikegohome - yes, I want to set an option to selected by its text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use jquery [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) like below

```
jQuery("#app_id option").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) ==  'Application 2'
}).prop('selected', true);
```

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hwe0wgn0/)***

Using ***BOOTSTRAP SELECT***,

```
jQuery("#app_id option").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) ==  'Application 2'
}).prop('selected', true);
$('#app_id').selectpicker('refresh');
```

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mwug1ybq/)***

Comment: My select drop down is rendered using Bootstrap Select plugin, so the above classic implementation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

  // Init selectpicker
  $('#app_id').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 4
  });

  // Set desired text 
  var optionToSet = "Application 1";

  $("#app_id option").filter(function(){
    // Get the option by its text
    var hasText = $.trim($(this).text()) ==  optionToSet;
    if(hasText){
    // Set the "selected" value of the <select>.
    $("#app_id").val($(this).val());
    // Force a refresh.
    $("#app_id").selectpicker('refresh')
    }
  });

});
```

Inspired by @Sathish's answer

[Working JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikegohome/gmu647bn/1/)