# How to set a selected value by using id on selectpicker plugin from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm testing the selectpicker plugin of bootstrap like this:

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="preffrom">
  <optgroup label="北海道" class="area-hokkaido">
    <option id="p01">北海道</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="東北" class="area-tohoku">
    <option id="p02">青森県</option>
    <option id="p03">岩手県</option>
    ...
    <option id="p07">福島県</option>
  </optgroup>
  ...
  <optgroup label="沖縄" class="area-okinawa">
    <option id="p47">沖縄県</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  // this event is for test  but it does not work...
  $('#test').bind('click', function(e){
    $('#preffrom').val('p03');
    $('#preffrom').selectpicker('refresh');
  });
});
```

I referenced this:
[How to set selected value on select using selectpicker plugin from bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap)

But nothing happens.
Please tell me correct way to select an `option` using id value.

Comment: is the test click even called? otherwise code seems correct

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('preffrom').value='p03';`

Comment: @Mikelis Baltruks Yes. And I also tested it using by DevTool's console. But it seems to be removed a `selectpicker`'s id when `$('#preffrom').val('p03')` executed.
Besides this, I modified it like this:
$('.selectpicker').val('p03');
But it didn't work.

Btw, this code works correctly:
$(".selectpicker").val("宮城県");
But I want to do it by id value.

Comment: @Vijai Thanks, but It seems to have changed the selectpicker's id value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is selected the #p03 option then `$('#p03').prop('selected', true);` should work (instead of `$('#preffrom').val('p03');`). Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kwm9rsee/

Comment: I didn't think of it.
It works!! It's very simple. Its very helpful.
Thank you!!