# how to select the default value of selectpicker using document ready?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I know it can be than by like this

```html
<option value="3" selected>3 minutes</option>
```

but the I need it on Jquery because the value will come from ajax database.

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
            Log out after  
            <select class="selectpicker" id="session_pick" name="session_pick" value="30">
              <option value="3">3 minutes</option>
              <option value="15">15 minutes</option>
              <option value="30">30 minutes</option>
            </select>
         </div>
```

Comment: `$('#session_pick').val('3');`

Comment: Something similar to your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select values using selectpicker methods

```
$('#session_pick').selectpicker('val', '3');
```

Reference:- https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerval

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using jQuery could be like

```js
$('#session_pick').val('3')
```

[jQuery.val() Line: 33](http://api.jquery.com/val/#example-1-2)