# How to set selected option with selectpicker plugin from bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using the Bootstrap-Select:

```
<select name="SelectAddress" class="selectpicker">
   <option value="a">Val 1</option>
   <option value="b">Val 2</option>
   <option value="c">Val 3</option>
   <option value="d">Val 4</option>
</select>
```

For example, I want to change `Val 1` to `Val 1.0` knowing `Val 1` is selected.
So I tried with no success:

```
$("select[name=SelectAddress]").text("Val 1.0");
$("select[name=SelectAddress]").selectpicker("refresh");
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**

Found a solution, by inserting an ID on each `<option>`:

```
<select name="SelectAddress" class="selectpicker">
   <option id="1" value="a">Val 1</option>
   <option id="2" value="b">Val 2</option>
   <option id="3" value="c">Val 3</option>
   <option id="4" value="d">Val 4</option>
</select>
```

Then:

```
$("#1").html("Val 1.0");
$("select[name=SelectAddress]").selectpicker("refresh");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap is this duplicate of this??

Comment: No, I don't want to change the value, but what is in `<option>...</option>`

Comment: please try below given solution...

Comment: this is it not efficient way giving id to each option you can use value attribute to set value of the option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set selected value on select using selectpicker plugin from bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
<select id="drop-down" name="SelectAddress" class="selectpicker">
   <option value="a">Val 1</option>
   <option value="b">Val 2</option>
   <option value="c">Val 3</option>
   <option value="d">Val 4</option>
</select>



$("#drop-down option[value='a']").text("Val 1.0");
$("select[name=SelectAddress]").selectpicker("refresh");
```

Comment: +1 Thanks this line solved my problem by putting it inside onShown:void(){ $("select[name=SelectAddress]").selectpicker("refresh"); } as I am using angular2 and JQuery selectpicker. and in html <option> tag I have put [attr.selected] attribute like [attr.selected]='(cartype.cartypesId==cartype.id)?"selected":null'

Comment: @sohaibjaved, if it work for you then please vote for me Thanks.