# How to set selected value in select picker from db?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a problem, here I use the `selectpicker` plugin from `Bootstrap` to select more than one, here I want to make a modal edit where it retrieves data from the previous data, which is a matter of previous data in the form of an array of how I set the value in the `selectpicker`
 this is my response data

```
0: {some data}
1: {some data}
2: Array(2)
0: "6"
1: "18"
```

How do i set the value in `selectpicker` with data from index array 2

this my HTML

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="loan_duration[]" id="loan_duration" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>                                 
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set selected value on select using selectpicker plugin from bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You could to something like this (if I understand your question correctly):

```
<option value="6" {{ in_array(6, $array) ? 'selected' : '' }}>6</option>
```

More about PHP [in_array() method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use @if @endif if the value is in array then add selected attribute

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="loan_duration[]" id="loan_duration" class="form-control" multiple>
              <option @if (in_array("6", $response[2])) "selected" @endif value="6">6</option>
              <option @if (in_array("9", $response[2])) "selected" @endif value="9">9</option>
              <option @if (in_array("12", $response[2])) "selected" @endif value="12">12</option>
              <option @if (in_array("15", $response[2])) "selected" @endif value="15">15</option>
              <option @if (in_array("18", $response[2])) "selected" @endif value="18">18</option>

                          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the array containing the values as a parameter to the `val()` method of your `select` element.

```js
var data = [{}, {},
  [6, 18]
];

$('#loan_duration').val(data[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="loan_duration[]" id="loan_duration" multiple>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
</select>
```

This will work with or without the bootstrap plugin.