# How to load the default selected values from ajax for bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using https://github.com/truckingsim/Ajax-Bootstrap-Select boostrap-select plugin to select the multi-select dropdown.

**What I can do:**

- Search drop drown data from ajax request
- select multiple values

**What is missing:**

- Default page load does not set DB values. (i have an ids list but I don't know how to load labels for corresponding ids)
  I can load drop-drown data searches through the drop-down.
  But I'm not able to set/load default selected values from ajax call during edit page load

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ajax-bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="form-group row required">
<label for="u-list" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Label</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker with-ajax" id="u-list" name="u-list" multiple data-live-search="true">
    </select>           
</div>
</div>
```

```js
    var list = {
            ajax          : {
                url     : 'ajaxhandle?action=getApps',
                type    : 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                // Use "{{{q}}}" as a placeholder and Ajax Bootstrap Select will
                // automatically replace it with the value of the search query.
                data    : {
                    term: '{{{q}}}'
                }
            },
            locale        : {
                emptyTitle: 'Select and Begin Typing'
            },
            log           : 3,
            preprocessData: function (data) {
                var i, l = data.length, array = [];
                if (l) {
                        console.log(data[i]);
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        array.push($.extend(true, data[i], {
                            text : data[i].label,
                            value: data[i].id,
                            data : {
                                subtext: data[i].label
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                }
                // You must always return a valid array when processing data. The
                // data argument passed is a clone and cannot be modified directly.
                return array;
            }
        };

        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker().filter('.with-ajax').ajaxSelectPicker(list);
        $('select').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

`Ajax-Bootstrap-Select` extends the existing `Bootstrap Select`.

The documentation for Bootstrap Select is here: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-menu

In order to show the selected values from the database you have to manually create the HTML for the `optgroup` inside the `<select></select>` tags and populate it with the selected values (`value` = `id` from the database, and the text between `<option></option>`)

```
<select class="selectpicker with-ajax" id="u-list" name="u-list" multiple data-live-search="true">
<optgroup>
    <option value="0" class="string" selected="selected">Ana</option>
    <option value="2" class="string" selected="selected">Sandra</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

This way `Ana` and `Sandra` will be selected by default when you load the page. You need to have the ids and labels already loaded from the database.

**Also check the working snippet below**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row required">
<label for="u-list" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Label</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="selectpicker with-ajax" id="u-list" name="u-list" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <optgroup>
                <option value="0" class="string" selected="selected">Ana</option>
                <option value="2" class="string" selected="selected">Sandra</option>
            </optgroup>
    </select>           
</div>
</div>
```

I tested this code on localhost with your javascript, and live searching was working. When I searched for `Maria` via AJAX, it was added to the currently selected values: `Ana` and `Sandra`.

Answer (score 0):

The docs dont make it look very obvious but I believe all you need to do to get default options to display is add them to the select element. Right now your code shows an empty select element.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker with-ajax" id="u-list" name="u-list" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Third</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

might be below code help you.

```js
var list = {
            ajax          : {
                url     : 'ajaxhandle?action=getApps',
                type    : 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                // Use "{{{q}}}" as a placeholder and Ajax Bootstrap Select will
                // automatically replace it with the value of the search query.
                data    : {
                    term: '{{{q}}}'
                }
            },
            locale        : {
                emptyTitle: 'Select and Begin Typing'
            },
            log           : 3,
            preprocessData: function (data) {
                var i, l = data.length, array = [];
                if (l) {
                        console.log(data[i]);
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        array.push($.extend(true, data[i], {
                            text : data[i].label,
                            value: data[i].id,
                            data : {
                                subtext: data[i].label
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                }
                // You must always return a valid array when processing data. The
                // data argument passed is a clone and cannot be modified directly.
                return array;
            }
        };
       // Suppose selected value is 1 then pass as below. if multi value then pass [1,2] array in val() funtion 
       $('select[name=u-list]').val(1);
       $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
       $('select').trigger('change');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<div class="form-group row required">
<label for="u-list" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Label</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="selectpicker with-ajax" id="u-list" name="u-list" multiple data-live-search="true">
    </select>           
</div>
</div>
```

More detail reference - [reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap)
[reference 2](https://github.com/truckingsim/Ajax-Bootstrap-Select/issues/177) [reference 3](https://codepen.io/Vadammt/pen/NgNVQx)