# How to click, but not select, an option in selectpicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to click on an option from the selectpicker, but it could not be selected in the checkbox. For example, I would just like to click on the "two" option but it cannot be selected after clicking.

How can I adjust the selectpicker for this?

My code:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="roomOne" class="form-label">Room One</label>
                <select name="roomOne" id="roomOne" class="form-control selectpicker">
                    <option value="1" data-value="one" dataset="pickerone">One</option>
                    <option value="2" data-value="two" dataset="pickerone">Two</option>
                    <option value="3" data-value="three" dataset="pickerone">Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="roomTwo" class="form-label">Room Two</label>
                <select name="roomTwo" id="roomTwo" class="form-control selectpicker">
                    <option value="1" data-value="one" dataset="pickertwo">One</option>
                    <option value="2" data-value="two" dataset="pickertwo">Two</option>
                    <option value="3" data-value="three" dataset="pickertwo">Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="roomThree" class="form-label">Room Three</label>
                <select name="roomThree" id="roomThree" class="form-control selectpicker">
                    <option value="1" data-value="one" dataset="pickerthree">One</option>
                    <option value="2" data-value="two" dataset="pickerthree">Two</option>
                    <option value="3" data-value="three" dataset="pickerthree">Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.selectpicker').on('change',function() {
            
            
            $("#roomOne option").show();
            $("#roomTwo option").show();
            $("#roomThree option").show();
            
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            
        });
    });
    
    /*
     I also tried this:
     
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
            // Seu código atual...
    
            // Interceptando o clique na opção "two"
            if (option === 'two') {
                var optionTwo = $("#roomTwo option[data-value='two']");
                optionTwo.prop('selected', !optionTwo.prop('selected'));
            }
        });
    */

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But it did not work.

The previous option select (which can be "one" or "three") should remain, instead of selecting the "two" option. Important: I need to click on the "two" option, I just can't select it. So using `disabled` doesn't work for this case.

Comment: Could you provide some more context as to what the overall goal of clicking the "two" option is? Is there some click event you are looking to trigger? Also what are you trying to avoid by not selecting the "two" option? There might be a workaround but I don't really know what your end goal is here.

Comment: @JeffreyGaydos I need to open an external dropdown menu. It is necessary to avoid just selecting "two" in the selectpicker as its functionality is in the external dropdown menu. However, I need to click to access the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like you need to do, you might want to consider not using this plugin and rolling your own select box functionality, but there is a workaround that I *think* solves your problem.

First, determine what value is currently selected in the select box and store it in a variable using: `var previousState = $('select[name=roomTwo]').val()`

Then click the "two" option however you were doing that before.

Then re-select whatever the user had selected previously using:

```
$('select[name=roomTwo]').val(previousState);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
```

See also: [How to set selected value on select using selectpicker plugin from bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804253/how-to-set-selected-value-on-select-using-selectpicker-plugin-from-bootstrap)